# What professional photography organizations are available to join?

Tags: professional

I'm interested in putting together a list (as comprehensive as possible) of the different professional photography organizations that can be joined. The criteria is relatively simple:

- An organization that caters specifically to some aspect of photography
- An organization which does not limit its membership to a single local community

Please list only one organization per answer, a link to the organization's website, and if an organization has a 'focus' (e.g. 'caters to photojournalists,' or 'caters to advertising photographers') call it out in the answer.

Comment: This is intended as a 'Community Wiki' question...

Comment: what's your feeling about ones that are groups of regional groups? eg: SmugMug's SMUGs, Pictage's PUGs.

Comment: My gut says to keep it at a 'national' level (whatever 'nation' the organization belongs to) or global in scope... But I could be convinced otherwise if there's a strong case for regional photography organizations that cater to the photography professional (e.g. not the hobbyist or semi-pro)...

Comment: Converted to CW.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad" - we'd close this on sight of it were posted today.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Organization:** [Professional Photographers of America](http://www.ppa.com/) (PPA)

**Focus:** None in particular.

Comment: I think those could all have been one answer.

Comment: Of course they *could* have. But the point in making them separate answers is (at least in part) so that others can add information about an individual organization in the comments if they feel a need to add extra detail, or start a discussion about a particular organization via the comments should they desire to. The question is Community Wiki so it's not like anyone gets any rep for answering, if that's what you're concerned about...

Comment: Quite the reverse. The organizations are all (presumably) good ones and the interests of the questioner would determine which ones to join. However someone coming to this answer because they want to ask the same thing a) might find one voted up for not better reason than it happened to match the interest of this individual asker (or the voter) and b) has to scroll down much further to get the complete list.

Comment: I suppose that if you *really* want to having them all in one answer you're welcome to roll 'em up and then flag all the individual answers for a mod to delete. Personally it sounds like you're proposing a solution in want of a problem.

Comment: I agree with DJClayworth.

Answer (score 1):

**Organization:** [Wedding and portrait Professionals International](http://www.wppionline.com/) (WPPI)

**Focus:** Wedding and portrait photography

Answer (score 0):

**Organization:** [National Press Photographers Association](http://www.nppa.org/) (NPPA)

**Focus:** Press and photojournalistic photography

Answer (score 0):

**Organization:** [American Photographic Artists](http://www.apanational.com/) (APA)

**Focus:** Advertising and media photography

Answer (score 0):

**Organization:** [British Press Photographers' Association](http://www.thebppa.com/) (BPPA)

**Focus:** Press and photojournalistic photography

Answer (score 0):

**Organization:** [Canadian Association of Photographers and Illustrators in Communications](http://www.capic.org/) (CAPIC)

**Focus:** Advertising, stock and media photography

Comment: It's still CAPIC, but the official expanded version is now Canadian Association of Professional Image Creators (probably to include those who wish to be regarded as "fine artists" rather than illustrators).

Answer (score 0):

**Organization:** [North American nature Photographers Association](http://www.nanpa.org/) (NANPA)

**Focus:** Nature photography

Answer (score 0):

**Organization:** [Picture Agency Council of America](http://www.pacaoffice.org/) (PACA)

**Focus:** Stock photography

Answer (score -2):

Nature Photography! An educational photos will give everyone a good details and description which they haven't seen in person yet.

Comment: Is this an organization (club, association, agency, etc.), or are you just mentioning a genre of photography?